# JavaScript runtime error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

Trying react js code on .net MVC, but while the time of rendering i am getting this error.

> JavaScript runtime error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is
>   not a DOM element.

Attaching the jsx code and html below. Please help me on this. Adding my react js file and html file below

**reactscript.jsx**

```
  var ItemDetailList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        var itemTable = this.props.data.map(function (itemarray) {

            return (
                <ItemArray>
                    <h4>itemarray.ServiceName</h4>
                    <p>itemarray.Description </p>
                </ItemArray>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div >
                {itemTable}
            </div>
        );
    }});

var ItemArray = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var TableExample = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({
                    data: data
                });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },

    render: function () {


        return (

            <ItemDetailList data={ this.state.data } />

        );
     }
 });

ReactDOM.render(< TableExample url={ "/Home/GetMenuDetails" } />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

**index.cshtml**

```
    @{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@*<!DOCTYPE html>*@


<html>

<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT INNER -->
<!-- END PAGE CONTENT INNER -->
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/react/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/JSX/ReactScript.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make sure that  `document.getElementById('container')` returns the div when the code runs?

Comment: yes it returns div